# Whose games should I collect for Benoni?

Tags: opening, famous-players, modern-benoni

I have been adopting the Benoni opening against 1 d4 recently with some moderate success. I would like to know whose games should I look at to have a good understanding. I see that [Tal](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=&playercomp=black&pid=14380&player=&pid2=&player2=&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=A56-A79&eco=&result=), and to a lesser extent [Fischer](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=&playercomp=black&pid=19233&player=&pid2=&player2=&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=A56-A79&eco=&result=), have practiced this opening in the past.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with Vugar Gashimov and Veselin Topalov.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Evargalo; Topalov made some novel contributions.  Even Kramnik popped out a Benoni in recent times.  Three time US Champion Nick De Firmian played it a lot as well.

You might consider this book by Marian Petrov: "Grandmaster Repertoire 12: The Modern Benoni".